# Trouble with multiple google maps on one table

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have an html table that contains 10 container for Google map

Below is the js function that create the map object

Function takes the lat and the lng of the map + the div element to insert the map to.

```
      function GetMap(lat,lng,number) 
      {
        var show_in=document.getElementsByClassName("map_conteiner")[number];
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(show_in,
            mapOptions);
            
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
             map: map,
             title:"Hotel"
           });
           
          $(show_in).fadeIn();
      }
```

The problem is that the map is displayed correctly only on the first invoke of this function

(No matter which div I start with)

after the firts invoke this function will allways present distorted maps (As you can see in the attached picture)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `trigger` the `resize`-event of the map in the `complete`-callback of `$.fadeIn()`

Furthermore you better create only 1 maps-instance for each `map_conteiner` and on subsequent calls of `GetMap` only set the new `center` of the existing map and the new `position` for the marker.

Comment: 1. correct me if iam wrong but i am using each 1 instance map_conteiner for each map_conteiner, every time the method create new google.maps.Map

2. can you be more specific - how do i trigger the resize-event of the map in the complete-callback of $.fadeIn()

Comment: 1. yes, you only have only 1 map-instance for each map_conteiner, but you create a new on each call of GetMap and discard the previously created instance(what isn't necessary, will slow down your application and also increases map-loads, what will be an important side-effect when you do this very often and use your maps-key) 2. `$(show_in).fadeIn(function(){google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');});`